# number of socket connection in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring, sockets, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, connection-pooling

I'm trying to understand how socket connections are open when connecting to Kafka using spring Kafka. I have the following code to connect to a Kafka topic named test which has 32 partitions.

application.yml

```
spring:
 kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: testbroker:9092     
    consumer:          
      enable-auto-commit: false
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      group-id: test
      properties:
        max.poll.records: 125
        partition.assignment.strategy: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
    
    listener:
      type: single
      ack-mode: batch
```

following java class to listen to Kafka topic

```
@Component
public class GenericKafkaMessageListener {
    
     @KafkaListener(topics = "test-topic", concurrency = "32") throws Exception {
         
         log.info("message - {}", message); 
         
     }
     
}
```

I'm trying to understand how many connections/socket connections are open in this case. I assume that these connections are long lived connection, I want to see if it is possible to can reuse these connection with some kind of connection pool. Thanks in advance

Comment: 'netstat' tool is useful to understand number of socket connection active on specific port.      execute following command ' netstat -an|grep 9092' , to monitor number of socket connection.

Comment: Thanks kus. That make sense but I'm trying to understand the internals of how it works

Answer (score 0):

The clients first connect to one of the bootstrap servers; the server responds with the advertised listeners for each broker and the clients then connect to those servers that are the leaders for individual topics/partitions; AFAIK, there is no way to share these connections.

Comment: Gary Russell, so each topic-partition will open a socket connection?

Comment: Also what role the concurrency property in the @KafkaListener play

Comment: Not each topic/partition, you will get a connection to each broker that hosts at least one partition. Concurrency > 1 means you will get that number of consumers. Each consumer will open a connection to each broker that hosts one or more of its assigned partitions. This is all managed by kafka-clients and is out of Spring’s control. There is no pooling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary. One last question, So if I don't specify concurrency then only one connection per broker is opened? let says I have 3 brokers in the cluster and 3 topics (at least one broker in each of 3 partitions), then total of 3 connections are opened?